# Trouble building the GCM Demo Server application

Tags: java, android, ant, google-cloud-messaging

Whenever I try to build the GCM Demo Server [from the documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) using `ant`, I get 17 compilation errors. It seems that some GCM libraries are missing. How can I resolve these issues?

```
 Errors:

  Buildfile: build.xml

init:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 7 source files to /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/build/classes
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:18: package com.google.android.gcm.server does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.android.gcm.server.Constants;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:19: package com.google.android.gcm.server does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:20: package com.google.android.gcm.server does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:21: package com.google.android.gcm.server does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:22: package com.google.android.gcm.server does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:46: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Sender
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet
    [javac]   private Sender sender;
    [javac]           ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:59: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Sender
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet
    [javac]   protected Sender newSender(ServletConfig config) {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:62: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Sender
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet
    [javac]     return new Sender(key);
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:81: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Message
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet
    [javac]         Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:81: package Message does not exist
    [javac]         Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:82: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Result
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet
    [javac]         Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:115: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class Message
    [javac]         Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:115: package Message does not exist
    [javac]         Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:116: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class MulticastResult
    [javac]         MulticastResult multicastResult;
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:123: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class Result
    [javac]         List<Result> results = multicastResult.getResults();
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:127: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class Result
    [javac]           Result result = results.get(i);
    [javac]           ^
    [javac] /root/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java:140: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: variable Constants
    [javac]             if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] 17 errors

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've never run this project myself, but it looks like it is missing the libraries from extras\google\gcm\gcm-server\dist\gcm-server.jar and its dependencies. Add these to the libs folder under this project and try again.

Comment: oh well i guess i solved it. Thanks for the information. 
What i did was that i copied build folder from gcm-server to gcm-demo-server and overwrite the existing one. Then ran ant and it compiled without errors.

Comment: it's explained in the README file "ant -f ../../gcm-server/build.xml update-demo"

Comment: The Google documentation should be updated although. Everyone who follows their instructions will get these compiler errors.